# Can Ice Witches use Winter markers on the turn they were earned?

Tags: small-world

The Ice Witches from "A Spider's Web" have the following ability:

> Ice Witches collect 1 Winter marker for each Magic Source they control at the end of their Redeployment phase. At the end of their Redeployment phase, Ice Witches may place their Winter markers in their own Regions or any adjacent Region (there cannot be more than 1 Winter marker per Region though). A Winter marker permanently augments the Region's defense by 1. It remains on the board as long as the Ice Witches are active. Regions with a Winter marker that are not controlled by an Ice Witch earn 1 less Victory coin than usual.

My initial reading of this was that you earned Winter markers on one turn and could use them on the next. This was due to the fact that both earning and using Winter markers happens on the same trigger - the "end of the Redeployment phase". In other words, by the time you've earned that turn's markers, the trigger that allows you to use them has already passed.

This would be similar to how the Fireball special power works, although that power specifies that Fireball markers are to be used on subsequent turns.

On further thought I realised I was *probably* reading into it too much and that the power is intended to be used immediately.

Still is there any verification as to which way is correct?

Answer (score 5):

They should be played the same round. The rule is not explicit and I have found no official statement. But [this topic on boardgamegeek took the same conclusion:](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1281097/ice-witches)

> All the magic sources do is indicate how many markers the Ice Witches may play at the end of their turn. Highlighted this bit as this is a rule we've got wrong a few times when playing.

Comment: I've been thinking about how to deal with this answer for a little bit because the discussion is between a couple of people rather than a general consensus. However, I think it is a worthwhile contribution to the context of the question as a whole. I think it deserves a +1 for that but I'll leave it unaccepted for the time being.